# How can I use `java.util.prefs` API to store an instance of Map<String,String>?

Tags: java, preferences

I would like to use the `Java.util.prefs` API to store an instanceof of `Map<String,String>`.

For good reasons, there is no `prefs.putObject()` method, which would be suitable for storing a `Map`.

Nevertheless, I think a String Map is simple enough to be treated as an exception to not store objects as preferences.

What would be a clever way to transform a String Map into a Preferences object?

Comment: You could prefix all map keys with something well-known and then use `<prefix>.<key>=<value>`. You just need to make sure none of the combinations of `<prefix> + <key>` can collide properties not related to map.

Comment: I don't see why you prefer `java.util.prefs` for storing a Map ? Instead use a `.properties` file ( [properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) and [e.g. here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/)) that you can load at the beginning of your program ?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I was thinking about that, but this does not work I think:

public class Prefs {

    private final static String mapKeysKey = "mapKeysKey";

    private final static String mapValuesKey = "mapValuesKey";

    public static void putMap(final Preferences prefs, final String mapIdentifier, final Map<String, String> map) {
 
 for (final Map.Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
     prefs.put(mapIdentifier + "-" + mapKeysKey, e.getKey());
     prefs.put(mapIdentifier + "-" + mapValuesKey, e.getValue());
 }
    }
}

Settings are overriden each time.

Comment: I actually meant it more like `map.forEach((key, value) -> prefs.put(mapIdentifier + "." + key, value));`. I also like what @svasa suggested - have a property file that is used specifially for that map and nothing else, and just store keys and values like they came.

Comment: OK, and How to get values back then? prefs.get(?);

Comment: @svasa does not work. p.put("id", map); will thow an Exception: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: Since you wouldn't know what keys are, `get()` won't work by itself. But you can call `keys()` and inspect all keys to take those that start with your `mapIdentifier`.

Comment: @kerner1000 What I mean is your map is `Map<String, String>` all you need is to define a properties file with format `key=value` format in each line. Look at the links provided in my earlier comment.

Comment: @svasa yes, you are right, that would work!